# How to convert viewbag string to int in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In mvc view page i have a view bag name passed from controller.

```
 <p class="plan-price">@item.Currency@item.Amount 
   <span class="plan-unit">
     per month 
   </span>
 </p>
```

For example, here `Amount` is 2900 means how to display 29 ?

Comment: Where did you use the `ViewBag`? Why `2900` should be `29`?

Comment: Its not a ViewBag, its a property of a model that you pass.

Comment: Amount is 2900 because it is passed from the controller as 2900.

Comment: Don't put a string in there in the first place. Besides, you show a Model, not a viewbag

Comment: @MohanSrinivas 2900 is 2900. If you want to display it as 29, just do the division in the controller and *don't* set the property to 2900. Or *don't* use a string property, use an integer property

Answer (score 2):

You can use all the usual C# number parsing methods when using Razor syntax e.g. `<p>@(int.Parse(Model.MyStringProperty)/100)</p>`

Remember that you will need to handle cases where the string is null, empty or not a number.

Comment: A better idea - set the *correct* value in the first place. And use the correct type, ie integer or decimal, for amounts

Comment: Error:Additional information: The best overloaded method match for 'int.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @foreach (var item in result){  <p class="plan-price">@item.Currency@(int.Parse(item.Amount) / 100)<span class="plan-unit">per month</span></p>}

Comment: item.Amount can't be a valid string therefore. What is its type?

Comment: What's the exception type you are getting? If you're getting a formatException, the string isn't something that can be parsed to an int.

Answer (score 2):

You can check null on the requisite string(in your case it is Amount), and then convert it using razor syntax:

```
@(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Amount) ? string.Empty : (Convert.ToInt32(Amount) / 100).ToString())
```